# Safari jquery a href onClick?

Tags: jquery, safari, hyperlink, onclick, href

This code works in IE, FF, etc. But not in Safari. I don't understand this.

I have a Link on my website:

```
<a href="/show/231" onClick="web('231')">Show</a>
```

Now the .js file:

```
function web(id) {
    $("#showIMG").load("/web", {
        id: id
    }, function() {});
}
```

"/web" is a PHP file (web.php). In the web.php is only a php code, that saves a value in the Database.

I Safari, the redirect (/show/231) works. But its not saving the value in the database. The "load" doesn't work.

I tested it like this here:

```
function web(id) {
    $("#showIMG").load("/web", {
        id: id
    }, function() {});
    alert('clicked');
}
```

The alert works. But not the load?

When I change the link to this

```
<a href="#" onClick="web('231')">Show</a>
```

the "load" works, but not the redirect to /show/231.

Comment: If someone gave the correct answer, please select it by clicking on the check mark below their vote tally.  Also, you might want to think about registering.  I merged your three accounts together.

Answer (score 1):

When Safari starts navigating to the next page, it stops your AJAX request.

To avoid this, you need to prevent the click (by adding `return false;` to the handler), then navigate explicitly by setting `location.href` in the AJAX completion handler.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the change of page cancelles the load of the image as the image will not be visible.

You could have the web metho call do the redirect using location.href = "" insted.

Answer (score 0):

Since the .load function is asynchronous, the AJAX request may not have time to execute before the browser navigates to "/show/231".

Given your example, I would try changing .load to .ajax and use the following parameters:

```
$.ajax({
    async: false, 
    url: '/web', 
    data: 'id=' + id, 
    success: function(){}
});
```

The 'async:false' parameter/value makes the AJAX request synchronous instead of asynchronous.... which should solve your problem.